# Reverse for 'profile-update' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['profile\\/update/(?P<pk>[\\-\\w]+)/']

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I'm getting this error,

```
Reverse for 'profile-update' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['profile\\/update/(?P<pk>[\\-\\w]+)/']
```

after the form validation getting that error.

I am unable to redirect it. How do I redirect to `profile-update`?

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def profile_update_view(request, pk):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
    form = UserProfileForm(instance=user)

    if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.id == user.id:
       if request.method == "POST":
           form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user)

        if form.is_valid():
            created_prof = form.save(commit=False)
            created_prof.user = request.user
            created_prof.save()

            return redirect('profiles:profile-update')

    return render(request, "profiles/profile_form.html", {
        "pk": pk,
        "form": form,
    })
else:
    raise PermissionDenied


class ProfileDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin,DetailView):
    template_name = 'profiles/profile_detail.html'

    def get_object(self):
    username = self.kwargs.get("username")
    if username is None:
        raise Http404
    return get_object_or_404(User, username__iexact=username, is_active=True)
```

**models.py**

```
def get_sentinel_user():
    return User.objects.get_or_create(username='deleted')[0]


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.SET(get_sentinel_user))
    profile_image = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='imgfolder/profile_image/')
    magz_cover_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, default='')
    website = models.URLField(default='', blank=True)
    bio = models.TextField(default='', blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, default='')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("UserProfile")
        verbose_name_plural = _("UserProfiles")

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.user.username)


def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs["instance"]
    if kwargs["created"]:
        user_profile = UserProfile(user=user)
        user_profile.save()
post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [

    re_path('update/(?P<pk>[\-\w]+)/', views.profile_update_view, name='profile-update'),
    re_path('(?P<username>[\w-]+)/', ProfileDetailView.as_view(), name='profile-detail'),

]
```

**template**

```
   <form action="." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
      {% csrf_token %}

     {{form.as_p}}   

    </form>
```

Comment: You did not give the `pk` keyword argument to the `redirect` call.

Comment: sir can you please explain little bit

Comment: sir can i redirect it to profile-detail

Answer (score 3):

Send pk to your profile-update view:
Edit this line from your code:

```
return redirect('profiles:profile-update', pk=pk)
```

For more details about redirect read this:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.redirect